# Unable to load CoreNLP Shift-Reduce model into CoreNLP jar

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

I don't understand how to load CoreNLP's Shift-Reduce Constituency Parser (SRCP) from my java app.

I'm using Apache Maven to manage my project's dependencies. Per the docs, the SRCP model is not bundled with CoreNLP, so I have downloaded stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar separately (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml) and placed that file in:

```
~/.m2/repository/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.5.2/stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar
```

That is the same directory as the core dependency jar

```
~/.m2/repository/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.5.2/stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar
```

Here is the relevant portion of my project's pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Compiling is successful:

```
mvn clean compile
```

But when I try to load the app, I receive:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
```

I unzipped the compiled project war, and "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz" is not present.

Here is how I'm calling the model in my app:

```
// Initialize a CoreNLP pipeline
public static Properties props = new Properties();
public static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

// Set the CoreNLP pipeline annotators.
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
props.setProperty("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

How can I update my Maven config to force my CoreNLP dependency to include the srparser model? Keep in mind that I need this configuration to run in other developers' environments, so the solution should be clean and reusable if possible.

Thanks!

EDIT:

In response to @jah's comment, below are the results of `mvn dependency:tree`. The build succeeds, but the srparser model is not compiled/present:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ [REDACTED] ---

Downloading:

...

[INFO] com.[REDACTED].nlp:nlp:war:0.1.0
[INFO] +- com.strategicgains:RestExpress:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.strategicgains:RestExpress-Common:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.strategicgains:DateAdapterJ:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.owasp.encoder:encoder:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.jollyday:jollyday:jar:0.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:jar:0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:models:3.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20151123:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
```

Comment: What happens when you do `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: It is interesting to see that there this version of that library in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22edu.stanford.nlp%22) with very different contents (mainly textfiles)

Comment: @jah I edited my post with the results of `mvn dependency:tree`. The srparser dependency is not present.

Comment: The dependency is present, it is the 6th line from the bottom. I guess this Jar is also included in your resulting war. I think  `edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz` is included too, via that said jar.

Comment: @jah the 6th line from the bottom actually refers to the default corenlp models jar, which does not include the srparser model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, download the srparser jar and place it in your project root: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar

Second, from the project root, execute the following command to install the srparser model dependency via Maven:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar -DgroupId=edu.stanford.nlp -DartifactId=stanford-srparser -Dversion=3.5.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Note the custom artifactId and lack of classifier in the command -- this is to prevent namespace confusion with the other CoreNLP modules.

Third, add the dependency to the Maven project's pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
         <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
         <artifactId>stanford-srparser</a‌​rtifactId>
         <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

Finally, clean install:

```
mvn clean install
```

If you continue to experience issues, it may be helpful to clear your Maven dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

And don't forget to add the download/install commands to your project README/environment bootstrap file!

(Thanks for your help @jah and @GaborAngeli.)

Answer (score 1):

To run the shift-reduce parser, you need to include the shift-reduce models jar, which can be found at: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml

Not sure if it's on maven, but it appears not?

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I realize that I need to include the shift-reduce models jar, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do so. I don't believe the jar is on Maven <http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22edu.stanford.nlp%22>. I'm pretty new to Java -- after I download the srparser jar, where do I place it so that it will be compiled in the correct namespace, and do I need to add any dependencies or tasks to my Maven pom.xml file?

Comment: In general, you just need to add it to your classpath, either with `-cp model.jar` or `CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:model.jar"`. For Maven, it looks like there's a `mvn install` command you can use to add it to your local repository: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Comment: You said you already putted your jars in your local repo, but maybe not in the correct way. To install a jar in the local reo you to `install`it. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) is a desription on  how to do that. you can then use the normal dependency mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the mvn command from the folder where the stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar is placed, then the following command should do the trick.

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar -DgroupId=edu.stanford.nlp -DartifactId=stanford-corenlp -Dversion=3.5.2 -Dclassifier=models -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: Your next exception will be `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "parse" requires annotator "pos"`

Comment: This is mostly correct. Two issues, though. First, this command would overwrite the existing models classifier jar with the srparser jar. My modified command: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar -DgroupId=edu.stanford.nlp -DartifactId=stanford-srparser -Dversion=3.5.2 -Dpackaging=jar`. Second, we need to add the installed dependency in our Maven pom.xml: `<dependency><groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId><artifactId>stanford-srparser</artifactId><version>3.5.2</version></dependency>`. Thanks for your help @jah!